# How to synchronize a SQL Server Express database and a remote database using a Windows service?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a Windows application (C#) which works on local database (in offline mode). When the network is up, the data should be moved to centralized server. The data should be synchronized on some interval using a Windows service.

The sync needs to be bi-directional.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to sync everything in the database, or just some tables? How big are the databases/changes?  Do you only have one client (local application), or could there be multiple clients?  Is there any concept of locking items whilst online, or could there be update conflicts where multiple clients change the same record whilst offline?

Comment: This sort of thing is built into Sql Server, isn't it?

Comment: I am trying to sync  two tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use merge replication and develop a windows service to invoke replication every so often (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337473.aspx)

Or you could use Synchronization Services for ADO .NET (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726015(v=sql.90).aspx)